# CDF of Binomial decreases with more trials.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $X \sim Bin(n, \frac{c}{n})$, and $Y \sim Bin(n+1, \frac{c}{n+1})$. We know that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = c$. I am curious to know whether
$$
\Pr[Y \leq c] \leq \Pr[X \leq c].
$$
I tried confirming this numerically for some values of $c$ and $n$, and it seems to hold, which suggests it would be true in general. However, I have no idea how to prove this. Any help or a counterexample would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As $n\to\infty$ you have that $P(X_{n}\leq c)\to 1/2$ so the sequence is bounded from below. Now assume for simplicity that $c$ is an integer. What happens with $P(X_n=x)$ as $n$ increases?

Comment: As $n \to \infty$, isn't $X_n$ behaving like a Poisson random variable with rate $c$? Is it a well-known fact that $\Pr[Y \leq c] = \frac{1}{2}$ when $Y \sim Poi(c)$? Also I am not sure how your last comment is related to the question; could you elaborate? We can assume $c$ is an integer, and this is not homework, so feel free to provide a full answer.

Comment: You can use the normal approximation of a binomial to compute the limit of that probability. What you should prove is that the binomial converges from above. If you think about it it is reasonable because the binomial is an asymmetric distribution but the normal is symmetric!

Comment: The approximation is a consequence of de moivre-Laplace theorem btw

Comment: I see your idea, but I'm not sure I understand your comment on showing that the binomial converges from above. Let's assume that $\Pr[X_n \leq c] \to \frac{1}{2}$, which seems reasonable given the approximation, but I'd have to think over again given the fact that we can also approximate a binomial by a Poisson and this would imply that $Pr[Y \leq c] = \frac{1}{2}$ when $Y \sim Poi(c)$, a fact which should be well-known.

Under this, then all that's left to show is that for $n = 2$ the claim is true and that $X_n$ behaves monotonically, no?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the median of the binomial distribution is either $\lfloor c\rfloor$ or $\lceil c\rceil$. Therefore if $c$ is an integer then

$$Pr\left[ Y\leq c\right]=Pr\left[X\leq c\right]=1/2$$

Now the non integer case.

This is also true if the median is $\lfloor c\rfloor$:

$$Pr\left[ Y\leq c\right]=Pr\left[Y\leq \lfloor c\rfloor\right]=1/2$$

and the same for $X$. What happens if the median is $\lceil c\rceil$? In that case we have that

$$Pr\left[ Y\leq c\right]=Pr\left[Y\leq \lfloor c\rfloor\right]=1/2-Pr\left[Y=\lceil c\rceil\right]$$

So all you need to do is compare $Pr\left[Y=\lceil c\rceil\right]$ with $Pr\left[X=\lceil c\rceil\right]$. I’m not sure that you can find a universal result for this comparison because some terms of $$Pr\left[Y=\lceil c\rceil\right]$$ are increasing in $n$ and others are decreasing. However if you look at the plot you can see that close to the mean the binomial converges to Poisson from above, so that would be a “visual proof” that your claim doesn’t hold. I am not sure about this last thing, though.

Comment: Since the distribution is not continuous, this definition of median is not correct. Specifically, the median is any number $c$ such that $\Pr[X \leq c] \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\Pr[X \geq c] \geq \frac{1}{2}$. Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Probability_distributions

For example, consider $n = 2$ and $c = 1$, i.e. two Bernoulli's with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. We have $\Pr[X \leq 1] = 1 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{4}$.